# Limite de upload para AWS S3

Tags: php, amazon-aws

Estou trabalhando com a [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) e [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/).

- Existe algum limite de tamanho de ficheiro a enviar?
- Existe algum limite de upload simultâneos?

É que tem me dado muito estes erros quando tento enviar 20 ficheiros de 200MB em simultâneo para o meu *bucket*.

> RequestTimeTooSkewedException: AWS Error Code: RequestTimeTooSkewed,
>   Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 0CE24AEDE4162AC9, AWS Error Type:
>   client, AWS Error Message: The difference between the request time and
>   the current time is too large.
>
> RequestTimeoutException: AWS Error Code: RequestTimeout, Status Code:
>   400, AWS Request ID: 913367E51F2BC5AD, AWS Error Type: client, AWS
>   Error Message: Your socket connection to the server was not read from
>   or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be
>   closed.

Ou será problema do meu código ou do PHP?

Comment: Verifique se o relógio está correto no computador.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente respondendo sua pergunta:

> - Existe algum limite de tamanho de ficheiro a enviar?

Sim. Usando upload em single operation o limite é de [5GB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html). Para multipart o limite é de [5TB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html). A Amazon recomenda usar multipart para arquivos maiores que 100MB.

O erro `RequestTimeTooSkewedException` normalmente ocorre quando o seu relógio está errado e você checar [comparando seu relógio com o da Amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25987429/2305521):

```
# Hora na Amazon (UTC)
$ curl http://s3.amazonaws.com -v

# Hora na sua Máquina (UTC)
$ date -u
```

No entanto o erro `RequestTimeoutException` provavelmente está ocorrendo por sua conexão com a internet ser lenta.

Se o seu relógio estiver certo então provavelmente seus uploads estão levando mais de 15 minutos, para mitigar isso recomendo que você use [multipart upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-large-files-using-multipart-uploads).